# Strange error nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed

Tags: swift

I'm new to swift and iOS in general, please keep that in mind.

I get this error when opening the CFReadStream. It does not matter if I open the read or write streams, the app always fails.

```
    var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
    let host: CFString = NSString(string: hostIP)
    let port: UInt32 = UInt32(self.VNCport)
    
    self.password = password
    
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, &readStream, &writeStream)

    inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    
    if readStream == nil {
        print("Erro read")
    }
    
    if writeStream == nil {
        print("Erro write")
    }
    
    inputStream!.delegate = self
    outputStream!.delegate = self
    
    inputStream!.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    outputStream!.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    inputStream!.open()
    outputStream!.open()
```

I made a clean project with just this function and a Button, the result is the same. No quic lib is used in the project.

Can someone help?

Comment: Does your app have any explicit reference to a library called "quic" anywhere?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. I made a search for the term and found nothing

Comment: Did you run this on the simulator and Xcode 12? it looks like Xcode 12 simulator has an issue related to libquic.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a simulator and the Xcode 12. What I would like to know is what is libquic?

Comment: I have the same problem doing a network call to an ext API and can confirm it is a simulator issue. It always fails (I am on iOS14) but the response is ok and get my data. So what it is?

Comment: I got the same issue, image fails to load with the above error in console. I am using KingFisher Swift framework to load the image.

Comment: Same issue here, Simulator 12.2, Xcode 12.2. iOS 14.2. Also on device.

Comment: Fast forward 4 months, and I'm having the same issue running a Rest API to my vapor server

Comment: Same issue here. Simulator/Xcode 12.4, iOS 14.4. I was using URLSession.shared.dataTask ... and post task result with DispatchQueue.main.async {...}

Comment: Same issues here in Xamarin using XCode 12.4 and Xamarin 5. Totally blocking all development on our iOS application. Literally, ground to a complete halt.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error in a different context, in XCode 12.0.1 too. It **might** not be related, but I suspect its an issue with accessing the run loop of the main thread. I was just trying out some introductory code I found online, and faced the same issue, so this is a bug, rather than a problem with your code. Here's how you can get a piece of code that has the same issue:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:BestKora/CS193P-Fall-2017-Demo-iOS12.git
cd "CS193P-Fall-2017-Demo-iOS12/Cassini L10"
xed . # this opens XCode (CLI tool stands for XCode editor)
```

---

Having said that, by rewriting the code, I was able to prevent this issue. Maybe you can find something amongst the code below to fix your specific issue:

Specifically, instead of using the following (`DispatchQueue.global`)

```swift
    private func fetchImage() {
        if let url = imageURL {
            spinner.startAnimating()
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
                let urlContents = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let imageData = urlContents, url == self?.imageURL {
                        self?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I use `URLSession.shared.dataTask`, and this error no longer happens:

```swift
    private func fetchImage() {
        print("fetching image")
        if let url = imageURL {
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }
                // maybe try dispatch to main
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: In my case I'm already using URLSession...and getting above error in console.

Comment: I'm seeing this error making API calls from a Xamarin Forms iOS application too. Seems the libquic library is made by a North Korean game company and stuffed into the iOS stack somewhere ... a bit random ...

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue in an Widget Target, but solved it by adding "public" to the variables.

Fixed struct is shown below.

```
struct LastCommitEntry: TimelineEntry {
    public let date: Date
    public let commit: Commit
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a Simulator message. It won't appear on a real device, and it doesn't affect the behavior of your app, so ignore it.

**I was getting this issue in url session.**

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

Restarting my simulator did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it started working when I encoded the data using `String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)` line:

```
if let safeData = data {
    
    let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)
    print(dataString!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with the model. I was working with Codable Model but it wasn't parsing the data properly. When I used the simulator the error was there but when I used my device it disappeared, neverthelesss, the collection view wasn't showing. When I change my model the error was corrected.

Answer (score -3):

You'll need to adopt that specific delegate you're using in your class.
Like in below example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

And don't forget to set your current class as the delegate, like below (for my own case):

```
IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!
searchTextField.delegate = self
```