# No Googlesheets API commands working after updated cocoa pods

Tags: swift, xcode, google-sheets-api

EDIT:  I get the following error upon google login:

"nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed"

not sure if this is related?

I had a fully working app that created, formatted and wrote to a googlesheet in my Google drive. I decided to create a copy of my app for some side development but was unable to run "pod install" in my terminal window which forced we to do a hard reset of my computer and reinstall everything from scratch. When I downloaded the new cocoa pods I was alerted that GTMOAuth2 had been depreciated to GTMAppAuth. After some googling I was able to find the changes to implement this new GTMAppAuth. I currently have my app running so that I get my google sign in pop up and am able to sign in fully however I have lost all functionality for my write/formatting/new sheet creation. Below are functions I would call in my script that originally worked fine but now no longer do since the update:

```
//==============================================================================================
//Write To Sheet Function
        
        func write() {
            let range = range1
            let updateValues = [[text1,text2,text3]]
            let valueRange = GTLRSheets_ValueRange() // GTLRSheets_ValueRange holds the updated values and other params
            valueRange.majorDimension = "ROWS" // Indicates horizontal row insert
            valueRange.range = range
            valueRange.values = updateValues
            let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesAppend.query(withObject: valueRange, spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range: range)
            query.valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"
            service.executeQuery(query) { ticket, object, error in}
        }

//==============================================================================================
//Merge Cell Function

            func mergecell() {

            let request = GTLRSheets_Request.init()
        
            request.mergeCells = GTLRSheets_MergeCellsRequest.init()
                
            let test = GTLRSheets_GridRange.init()
            
            test.startRowIndex = rowstart
            test.endRowIndex = rowend
            test.startColumnIndex = columnstart
            test.endColumnIndex = columnend
            request.mergeCells?.range = test
            request.mergeCells?.mergeType = kGTLRSheets_MergeCellsRequest_MergeType_MergeRows

            let batchUpdate = GTLRSheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.init()
            batchUpdate.requests = [request]
            
            let createQuery = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsBatchUpdate.query(withObject: batchUpdate, spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId)
       
            service.executeQuery(createQuery) { (ticket, result, NSError) in
            
            }
           }



//==============================================================================================
//Clear Sheet Data Function
        
        func Clearsheet() {
            
        let range = "A2:Q"
            let rangeToAppend = GTLRSheets_ClearValuesRequest.init();
            let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesClear.query(withObject: rangeToAppend, spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId, range: range)
            service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, result, error) in
            }
        }
```

I've been working on this for 3 weeks now and feel exhausted with it so I decided to reach out to the online community. And help or input is deeply appreciated.

Thank you,

Michael

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64029844/strange-error-nw-protocol-get-quic-image-block-invoke-dlopen-libquic-failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of: stackoverflow.com/questions/64029844/… – Code-bear456 27 secs ago
Trivial answer converted to comment